# When using CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync how can I use II or && in my lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, roslyn, asp.net-core-2.1

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 2.1 API and I am trying to pass a lambda expression as a string in the body of a POST, which is then evaluated in my repository to return a set of records. I am following [this blog post](https://www.strathweb.com/2018/01/easy-way-to-create-a-c-lambda-expression-from-a-string-with-roslyn/) and using CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync to parse the string and generate the lambda in a form I can use in my linq query WHERE clause.

It works great with single items. For example, if I pass

```
"f => f.CompanyName.Contains(\"Dav\")"
```

I get the desired record set returned.

However, if I try...

```
"f => f.CompanyName.Contains(\"Dav\") || f.PrimaryContactTitle.Contains(\"Dav\")"
```

I get an exception stating...

```
System.NullReferenceException: Arg_NullReferenceException
at Submission#0.<>c.<<Initialize>>b__0_0(Company f)
at System.Linq.Utilities.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`1.<CombinePredicates>b__0(TSource x)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.ToArray()
at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.GetEnumerator()+MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.GetCount(Boolean onlyIfCheap)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
```

when I try to work with the resultant IQueryable collection.

Is there some alternative to using || or && as OR and AND operators in a linq query lambda expression that can be correctly parsed by CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync?

Here is an example of my request body;

```
{
    "filter":""f => f.CompanyName.Contains(\"Dav\") || f.PrimaryContactTitle.Contains(\"Dav\")",
    "pageNumber": 1,
    "pageSize": 20,
    "deleteFlag": false,
    "orderBy": "CompanyName desc",
    "Fields": null 
}
```

Here is my relevant repo code...

```
  public async Task<PagedList<Company>> GetFilteredPagedList(CompaniesResourceParameters resourceParams)
    {
        try
        {

            var options = ScriptOptions.Default.AddReferences(typeof(Company).Assembly);
            var companyFilterExpression = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<Func<Company, bool>>(resourceParams.Filter, options);

            //Get the records ordered by the OrderBy property of the passed in resourceParams
            var collectionBeforePaging =
                _manifestContext.Companies
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(c => c.Sites)
                .Where(companyFilterExpression).AsQueryable()
                .Where(d => d.DeleteFlag == false)
                .ApplySort(resourceParams.OrderBy, _propertyMappingService.GetPropertyMapping<CompanyDto, Company>());


            return PagedList<Company>.Create(collectionBeforePaging,
                resourceParams.PageNumber,
                resourceParams.PageSize); // <-- This is where the Exception is thrown as it tries to work with the collectionBeforePaging
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, $"Exception trying to retrieve a paged list of records using the filter {resourceParams}"); 
            throw;

        }
    }
```

The exception occurs when I hit the line...

```
return PagedList<Company>.Create(collectionBeforePaging,
                resourceParams.PageNumber,
                resourceParams.PageSize)
```

Here is the Create method that is being called when the exception happens.

```
public static PagedList<T> Create(IQueryable<T> source, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
        {
            var count = source.Count();
            var items = source.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
            return new PagedList<T>(items, count, pageNumber, pageSize);
        }
```

The exception occurs when I try to use the IENumerable in the line

```
var count = source.Count();
```

This exception does not occur when I use a filter that does not have an OR or AND, such as..

```
filter":"f => f.CompanyName.Contains(\"Dav\")"
```

or

```
filter":"f => f.PrimaryContactName.Contains(\"Dav\")"
```

So, I believe the issue is with the use of the || operator.

*** UPDATE 1 ***

As NineBerry pointed out, I was not doing a null check before doing the *.Contains() in my lambda. Here is my full revised filter that I am passing into the HttpClient API request in my client.

```
       var filter = $"f => f.CompanyName.Contains(\"{searchValue}\") || " +
                     $"(f.PrimaryContactName != null && f.PrimaryContactName.Contains(\"{searchValue}\")) || " +
                     $"(f.PrimaryContactTitle != null && f.PrimaryContactTitle.Contains(\"{searchValue}\")) || " +
                     $"(f.PrimaryContactTitle != null && f.PrimaryContactTitle.Contains(\"{searchValue}\")) || " +
                     $"(f.PrimaryContactEmail != null && f.PrimaryContactEmail.Contains(\"{searchValue}\"))";
```

And now my search filter works as expected.

This also verifies that I can use || and && in my lambda string that is being parsed by CSharpScript.ExecuteAsync() withou any special handling.

Comment: There is also the possibility that sometimes `PrimaryContactTitle` is `null`.  You have only tested `PrimaryContactName` so far...

Comment: If you are 100% certain that `PrimaryContactTitle` can never be null, please provide an [mcve].

Comment: @NineBerry, you are correct. The issue was trying to do a Contains with a null value. I knew it had to be something simple but I just wans't seeing it. Thanks. if you want to post this as an answer, I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: It's good that you found the original issue. But it would be better if you use `EvaluateAsync<Expression<Func<Company, bool>>>` to get expression instead of func. Then you won't need `.AsQueryable()` after `Where` and more importantly, the filtering will be performed server side (database) rather than retrieving the whole table and filtering in memory as it is now. That also would eliminate the need of `null` checks because SQL handles them naturally.